# Python can't find my packages:

Tags: python

I have been able to run a web app I wrote in bottle from my IDE. It works well, and when I tried to move it to a new system, it broke (couldn't find the files I wrote in the lib folder).

How do I get it to find my lib files? I found this for bottle:

```
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0,'/absolut/path/to/templates/')
```

And I think that will help with the missing .tpl files, but how do I do this for python in general? Can I add some sort of `python.PATH.insert()` to my main.py?

Here is my dir structure:

```
DEV
├───.idea
│   ├───inspectionProfiles
│   └───scopes
└───myProject *(Also has a .py file I need)*
    ├───output
    │   └───processed
    └───webapp
        ├───src
        │   ├───lib
        │   │   └───*(All my .py files I need)*
        │   ├───static
        │   │   ├───css
        │   │   ├───files
        │   │   ├───img
        │   │   └───js
        │   └───views *(All the .tpl files I need)*
        │       ├───main
        │       ├───popup
        │       └───reports
        └───main.py *(The file that acesses the .py files)*
```

Relevant Code:

```
import threading
import time
import datetime

import crud_ops
from helper_functions import load_config_file, dt_ona_sum_format
from server import run_bottle
from myProject import ona_sum_tool #THIS LINE HERE

 ...


def run_queue(col):

    while(1):
        if not col:
            print "Unable to connect to db."
        else:
            my_limit = 10
            processing_cursor = col.queue.find({"status":"processing"}).limit(my_limit)
            if not processing_cursor.count():
                queued_cursor = col.queue.find({"status":"queued"}).limit(my_limit)
                if queued_cursor.count():
                    for doc in queued_cursor:
                        print col.queue.update({"_id":doc['_id']},{"$set":{"status":"processing"}} )
                # print col.queue.update({"status":"queued"}, {"$set":{"status":"processing"}}).limit(10)
                    processing_cursor = col.queue.find({"status":"processing"})
            if processing_cursor.count():
                time.sleep(1)
                for doc in processing_cursor:
                    ############################# THIS LINE HERE ######################
                    new_file_name = ona_sum_tool.run_summary(dt_ona_sum_format(doc['start']), dt_ona_sum_format(doc['end']))
                    # print "new_file_name: ", new_file_name
                    old_id = doc['_id']
                    # print old_id
                    doc['_id'] = str(new_file_name)
                    doc['status'] = 'done'

                    insert_result = col.queue.insert(doc)
                    if(insert_result):
                        col.queue.remove({"_id":old_id})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lib.threads import ConnectToDBThread, StartBottleThread, ProcessOutputController, \
  File "C:\dev\myProject\myProject\webapp\src\lib\threads.py", line 10, in <module>
    from myProject import ona_sum_tool
ImportError: No module named onager
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have forgotten to put the the `__init__.py` file in your `lib` folder. [Here's why you need the `__init__.py` file](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Comment: I have that file in my lib folder. I also have it in a couple other folders... could that be a problem?

Comment: If you want to access files in your `lib` folder from your `main.py` then your `src` folder needs to have a `__init__.py` file as well. I'm not sure where all the other `__init.py` files are but that shouldn't be the problem anyway.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to show the relevant code in `main.py` and the error you get as well.

Comment: This helped me fix most of the issue, but if I had another python file in "myProject" how could I access that from say, `src.lib`